# Angular.JS Custom Directive doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the next problem. I'm doing the official Angular.js tutorial and tryin to run from myself all their examples. I don't have any idea why those directives doesn't work in my project, while on their website are working. 
'Not working' means the directives are doing nothing in this case. I'm expecting to see the images gallery specificated in product-gallery.html.
It's verry frustrating. Bellow you have the index.html and the .js file. The angular.min.js, app.js, bootstrap.min.css files are in the same folder as index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">

<!--  Products Container  -->
<div class="list-group">
  <!--  Product Container  -->
  <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
    <h3>{{product.name}} <em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}</em></h3>

    <!-- Image Gallery  -->
    <product-gallery></product-gallery>

    <!-- Product Tabs  -->
    <product-tabs></product-tabs>

  </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The .js file:

```
(function() {
 var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

app.directive('productGallery',function(){
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'product-gallery.html',
  controller: function(){
    this.current = 0;
        this.setCurrent = function(imageNumber){
        this.current = imageNumber || 0;
        };
  },
  controllerAs: 'gallery'
  };
});

app.controller('StoreController', function() {
this.products = gems;
});

app.controller("ReviewController", function(){

this.review = {};

this.addReview = function(product){
  product.reviews.push(this.review);
  this.review = {};
};

});

app.directive("productDescriptions", function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: "product-description.html"
};
});

app.directive("productReviews", function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: "product-reviews.html"
};
});

app.directive("productSpecs", function() {
return {
  restrict:"A",
  templateUrl: "product-specs.html"
};
});

app.directive("productTabs", function() {
return {
  restrict: "E",
  templateUrl: "product-tabs.html",
  controller: function() {
    this.tab = 1;

    this.isSet = function(checkTab) {
      return this.tab === checkTab;
    };

    this.setTab = function(activeTab) {
      this.tab = activeTab;
    };
  },
  controllerAs: "tab"
};
});

var gems = [
{
  name: 'Azurite',
  description: "Some gems have hidden qualities beyond their luster, beyond     their shine... Azurite is one of those gems.",
  shine: 8,
  price: 110.50,
  rarity: 7,
  color: '#CCC',
  faces: 14,
  images: [
    "1.png",
    "images/gem-05.gif",
    "images/gem-09.gif"
  ],
  reviews: [{
    stars: 5,
    body: "I love this gem!",
    author: "joe@example.org"
  }, {
    stars: 1,
    body: "This gem sucks.",
    author: "tim@example.org"
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Bloodstone',
  description: "Origin of the Bloodstone is unknown, hence its low value. It has a very high shine and 12 sides, however.",
  shine: 9,
  price: 22.90,
  rarity: 6,
  color: '#EEE',
  faces: 12,
  images: [
    "2.png",
    "images/gem-07.gif",
    "images/gem-04.gif"
  ],
  reviews: [{
    stars: 3,
    body: "I think this gem was just OK, could honestly use more shine, IMO.",
    author: "JimmyDean@example.org"
  }, {
    stars: 4,
    body: "Any gem with 12 faces is for me!",
    author: "gemsRock@example.org"
  }]
  }, {
    name: 'Zircon',
    description: "Zircon is our most coveted and sought after gem. You will pay much to be the proud owner of this gorgeous and high shine gem.",
    shine: 70,
    price: 1100,
    rarity: 2,
    color: '#000',
    faces: 6,
    images: [
      "3.png",
      "images/gem-07.gif",
      "images/gem-07.gif"
    ],
    reviews: [{
      stars: 1,
      body: "This gem is WAY too expensive for its rarity value.",
      author: "turtleguyy@example.org"
    }, {
      stars: 1,
      body: "BBW: High Shine != High Quality.",
      author: "LouisW407@example.org"
    }, {
      stars: 1,
      body: "Don't waste your rubles!",
      author: "nat@example.org"
    }]
}
];
})();
```

And the product-gallery directive html page, for example:

```
  <div  ng-show="product.images.length">
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img ng-src="{{product.images[gallery.current]}}" />
      </div>
      <ul class="img-thumbnails clearfix">
        <li class="small-image pull-left thumbnail" ng-repeat="image in product.images">
          <img ng-src="{{image}}" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Explain what the desired outcome, what you are seeing, whether there are errors, etc...

Comment: 'Not working' means the directives are doing nothing in this case. I'm expecting to see the images gallery specificated in product-gallery.html.

Comment: Use some alert() [e.g. window alert] http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp in your code and verify things at various places to see where thing are working and where they are not working and maybe you can narrow it down that way and figure out what the problem is and fix it.

Comment: The code you have posted will most certainly give some errors in your console. this.products = gems; gems does not exist in your code you pasted.

Comment: I pasted this into a plunker (and if you did so yourself, it would help us help you) - all seem to be working. http://plnkr.co/edit/432tj45fFTVmEIOy8SXb?p=preview

Comment: Ty much for your answers. Thanks, it works in plunker, but it seems to don't work in my browser, tried in 3 different browsers.:( So, the problem it wasn't in my code, it is somewhere else. Thank you for your efforts. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code into Plunker and included these lines in the `<head>` section of my index.html.  You need to make certain that Jquery, Bootstrap, and Angular are properly loaded in your project.  Jquery needs to be before Bootstrap since Bootstrap depends on it.  Once I added these dependencies, the AngularJS directives in your code worked.  If you're working in Visual Studio, you could add these to your project through the NuGet Package Manager.

```
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Is working in Plunker, but idk why it's not working on my browsers. Trying to fix this right now.:) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because you are opening html documents (your directive html code) directly from the browser. Just serve your code from a webserver and access it on localhost.

Go to directory of your project in a console
and type: (you need python 3 installed for that)

```
python -m http.server [<portNo>]
```

Then access your website in your browser, just put `localhost:8000` as an address